# WTSFreeMemory hangs when called from service during startup - should I omit?

Tags: c++, winapi, service

When my service is started by the system at startup, it's status remains as `SERVICE_START_PENDING` for some time and then terminates (or gets terminated, I don't know). If I start the service manually while the system is up, everything works fine.

While looking for a reason I came to the insight that something happens **somewhere within** [WTSFreeMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsfreememory) (FYI: I want to check if a user is currently logged on via [WTSEnumerateSessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsenumeratesessionsw)) - **the function never returns**. In addition to that, this only happens if no user is logged on.

Now I am confused regardings the usage of WTSFreeMemory. Currently I am up to omit `WTSFreeMemory` (at least for the case that no users are logged on interactively) - but this results in leaking of memory, isn't it? "Backing up" the pointer and use WTSFreeMemory later is also not good solution because "looking the for interactive user" may happen several times (I become notified when users log on or off).

Do you have any suggestions or is there something to know about WTSFreeMemory that is not (clearly) stated in the documentaion? Have much thanks in before.

```
// Look if the user is the interactive user
WTS_SESSION_INFOW *sessionData = nullptr;
DWORD numSessions;
DWORD sessionId = static_cast<DWORD>(UTILS_GENERIC_FAILURE);

if (!WTSEnumerateSessionsW(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, 0, 1, &sessionData, &numSessions))
{
    return (UTILS_GENERIC_FAILURE);
}

for(quint32 loop = 0; loop < numSessions; loop++, sessionData++)
{
    if (sessionData->State == WTSActive)
    {
        sessionId = sessionData->SessionId;
        break;
    }
}

// Calling WTSFreeMemory hangs for some reason if currently no user is logged on
if (sessionData)
{
    WTSFreeMemory(sessionData);
}
```

Comment: `WTSFreeMemory` of course will not hang if you pass to it correct memory address

Comment: I pass the pointer that was returned by WTSEnumerateSessions, the variable ppSessionInfo is inialized with nullptr and is even checked before to avoid calling WTSFreeMemory() with a nullptr....

Comment: better show your code. and at begin try run exactly such code in test app

Comment: `WTSFreeMemory` simly call `LocalFree` - which just `HeapFree` from process heap. if `WTSFreeMemory` hung - almost any memory in process hung. your problem say that you pass wrong pointer or corrupt heap( may be even in another place). but problem not in `WTSFreeMemory`

Comment: possible you change `ppSessionInfo` and not remember original value (very common mistake here) or you corrupt heap in another operation

Comment: I have added the code (see above) - is there something wrong? Testing: As stated above, everything works fine if I try this when system is already up - thre problem occours only when the system (It's Win7 32bit for now) is starting up....

Comment: of course your code is wrong. you do `sessionData++` ? i wrote *possible you change ppSessionInfo and not remember original value (very common mistake here)*

Comment: do `void* pv = sessionData` and in the end `WTSFreeMemory(pv)`

Comment: and instead `for` loop and additional `loop` simply do `if (numSessions) do {.. } while(++sessionData, --numSessions)`

Comment: Oh my god - I see, this is very painful. I misinterpreted "possible you change ppSessionInfo" as suggestion instead of a question. The only thing I wonder about is that this only has impact in this pecific situation ... however, do you want to post the answwer so that I can confirm? Much thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to enumerate sessions at all, instead of processing `SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE` notifications in your `HandlerEx` callback?

Comment: I also process `SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE`, in my case I am waiting/checking for the user that interactively logs on/is logged on (locally, not remote).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a mistake on my own: I modified the pointer that was returned by `WTSEnumerateSessionsW` (see the `sessionData++` in my code) and therefore passed an invalid address to `WTSFreeMemory()`.

Thanks to RbMm for help.